# How do I load content based on first spinner?

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

I am not sure why this isn't working.  I am getting a Log Cat error stating FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointer Exception at com.example.bertin.HotelLocation.onItemSelected.  Here is the code.  The  onItemSelected seems correct to me maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.

```
package com.example.bertin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class HotelLocation extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner countrySpinner, citySpinner;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> cityAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel_location);

        Spinner countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelCountry);
        Spinner citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelCity);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
        // layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> countryAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.countries,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cityAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.australia,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        countryAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        cityAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
        citySpinner.setAdapter(cityAdapter);

        countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // citySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        String[] citySpinnerArray = null;
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selected.equals("Australia")) {

            citySpinnerArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.australia);


        }
        citySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, citySpinnerArray));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hotel_location, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

StackTrace:

```
09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160): java.lang.NullPointerException

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at com.example.bertin.HotelLocation.onItemSelected(HotelLocation.java:97)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

09-10 03:42:02.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2160):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 97. looks like `citySpinnerArray` is null. move this `citySpinner.setAdapter` inside the if block and try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Just replace this two line your code working perfectly.
Spinner countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelCountry);
Spinner citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelCity);
                   to
countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelCountry);
citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerHotelCity);
```

Comment: Excellent catch. You should provide a bit of explanation with your answer though.

Comment: My bad i forgot i declared it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        String[] citySpinnerArray = null;
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selected.equals("Australia")) {

            citySpinnerArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.australia);

            citySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, citySpinnerArray));
        }
}
```

Comment: @Ketan `this` refers to the activity's context here. There is no anonymous inner class where using `HotelLocation.this` would have made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        if (selected.equals("Australia")) {


        citySpinner.setAdapterArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.australia,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item));


        }

    }
```

Comment: .setAdapterArrayAdapter is giving me an error i think that's a typo.